# Replacing three-wire timed switch with a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, switches, timer, light, 3-wire

The building is surrounded by 6 lights and 4 buttons, 3 of which are illuminated.

Right now the circuit is managed by a [Perry 1IT 1051](https://www.perry.it/en/prodotto/1it-1051-1.aspx). Here are the official schematics:

[image: Schematic]
[image: Schematic]

While I'm happy with the basic functionality offered by the product, I would like to make the circuit "smarter":

1. Keeping a button pressed for a few seconds should turn on/off the lights without the timer.
2. Pressing a button shortly when the lights are turned on should (re)start the timer.

Programming the functions on a microcontroller such as ESP8266 is not an issue.

My question is: how should I connect the device without changing the existing wiring?

Comment: Edited, I clarified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Perry 1IT 1051 has three terminals for the following connections:

1. Terminal # 1 for 230 V ~ utility power
2. Terminal # 2 for 230 V ~ to the lamps
3. Terminal # 3 that is to be momentarily connected to neutral through one
   of the push button switches.

The existing wiring need not be changed provided that:

1. One of the controller outputs energises a relay, with 16 A - 250 V
   AC contacts, to turn on the lamps.
2. One of the controller inputs is energised through a relay,
   actuated by a momentary push button switch, in the 230 V AC circuit.

[image]  [image]

Comment: I acquired a [SONOFF MINIR2](https://sonoff.tech/product/diy-smart-switches/minir2) and a generic NO relay that bonds S1 and S2 when activated.

I pretty much followed your suggestion, with the difference that I only need two devices (the MINIR2 has an integrated relay).

Everything seems to be working as it should, thank you!

Comment: For reference, the Tasmota rule is `ON Switch1#state=3 DO Backlog; PulseTime1 0; Power1 toggle ENDON ON Switch1#state=2 DO Backlog; PulseTime1 600; Power1 on ENDON`.

Comment: Anytime, Davide! I'm glad you arrived at a simpler solution. Thank you.

Comment: I have found an even simpler solution: the [SONOFF MINIR4](https://sonoff.tech/product/diy-smart-switches/minir4) allows to connect either neutral (as in my case) or live directly to S2!

Also, I forgot to mention: SwitchMode is set to 5 (push-button with long press) and Option114 is ON (switch detached from respective relay).

Comment: Thank you for the update, Davide.